# Unable to print values from Java program

Tags: java

I'm coding a knights tour program for a project and I have to print out starting coordinates, move count, and ending coordinates but they won't print. The code compiles I just can't get it to print the values at the end. I left out the instance field because it said I'm not allowed to post that much code.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class NonHeuristic {

public static boolean boundCheck() {
    if((randX + x) <= 7 && (randX + x) >= 0) 
        if((randY + y) <= 7 && (randY + y) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void moveGenerator() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int z = 0;

    while(z == 0){
    randX = rand.nextInt(5) - 2;
        if(randX % 2 == 0 && randX != 0) {
            randY = rand.nextInt(3) - 1;
                if(randY != 0 && boundCheck() && newMoveCheck()) {
                    xMove = randX;
                    yMove = randY;
                    z = 1;
                }//close nested if
        }//close if 
        else if(randX % 2 != 0 && randX != 0) {
            randY = rand.nextInt(5) - 2;
                if(randY != 0 && Math.abs(randY) > 1 && boundCheck() && newMoveCheck()) {
                    xMove = randX;
                    yMove = randY;
                    z = 1;
                }//close nested if
        }//close if loop
    }//close while loop 
}//close moveGenerator


public static void startPoint() {
    Random start = new Random();
    xStart = start.nextInt(8);
    x = xStart;

    yStart = start.nextInt(8);
    y = yStart;
//System.out.println(xStart + " " + yStart);
}//close startPoint

public static boolean newMoveCheck() {
    if(chessboard[randX + x][randY + y] == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}//close newmoveCheck

public static void firstMove(){
    moveCount = 0;
    startPoint();
    chessboard[x][y] = moveCount;
    moveCount ++;
}//close firstMove
public static void move() {

    for(int i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
        moveGenerator();
        chessboard[x + xMove][y + yMove] = moveCount;
        moveCount ++;
        x = x + xMove;
        y = y + yMove;
    }
    xEnd = x;
    yEnd = y;


}//close move


}
public class NonHeuristicApplication extends NonHeuristic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
            firstMove();
            move(); 

            System.out.print("[" + xStart + "," + yStart + "]," + moveCount + ",[" + xEnd + "," + yEnd + "]");

        }
    }

} //close class
```

Comment: Parts of the code are missing such as the definition of `xStart` and `yStart`, and the method `startPoint()`. Does your code compile? Can you add the missing code required to get it to compile? This will help us to answer your question.

Comment: Can you explain how you are executing your code? What you are seeing, any compilation error, any runtime exception ... As said by Jason, without the declaration, it could be a simple `NullPointerException`, like your array not initialized.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the first line of your main and step through to the print?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing so far we've only seen code that won't compile. Unless the OP has not posted his/her actual code, putting breakpoints in the file won't do anything.

Comment: @Stultuske I am assuming/hoping that the missing code is just not posted. But if it doesn't run, then the source of the issue is found :-)

Comment: @Jason I just added the whole first part of my program minus the instance field but all the variables I use were instantiated.

Comment: @AxelH The code complies but when I run it nothing happens and I have to terminate it.

Comment: That is not the complete code or you are wrong that it compiles, lot of variables that are not declared in your code. I would suggest not making everything static and instead work with objects and instance variables.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson                                                                              public static int moveCount;
 private static int[][] chessboard = new int[8][8];
 private static int xMove;
 private static int yMove;
 private static int x;
 private static int y;
 private static int randX;
 private static int randY;
 public static int xStart;
 public static int yStart;
 public static int xEnd;
 public static int yEnd;                                         I left all these out because stack overflow wouldn't let me post the question with all that code

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that, anyway your code has so many variables I am convinced that the only way to figure out what's wrong is by using the debugger and step through all those move and check methods. Or see if you can re-factor your code to get ride of some of those variables.One thing though, are you sure you want to call the method named `firstMove`  for every iteration in the loop, perhaps it should be called before the loop? And why a sub-class, move the `main` method to the superclass and delete the sub-class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not understand `static` variable. Your code is not compilable. To print required data, you have to get an instance with these values. It could be given `NonHeuristic` class.

Remember, that `static` variables and methods belong to `class` object but not to the `class' instance`, therefore all static variables and methods are the same for all instances for given class.

```
public class NonHeuristic {

    private static final int SIZE = 8;

    private final int[][] chessboard = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
    private final Random random = new Random();

    private int xStart;
    private int yStart;
    private int moveCount;
    private int xEnd;
    private int yEnd;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int randX;
    private int randY;
    private int xMove;
    private int yMove;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        NonHeuristic obj = new NonHeuristic();

        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
            obj.firstMove();
            obj.move();
            System.out.print("[" + obj.xStart + ',' + obj.yStart + "]," + obj.moveCount + ",[" + obj.xEnd + ',' + obj.yEnd + ']');
        }
    }

    public void firstMove() {
        moveCount = 0;
        startPoint();
        chessboard[x][y] = moveCount;
        moveCount++;
    }

    public void startPoint() {
        xStart = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        x = xStart;

        yStart = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        y = yStart;
        System.out.println(xStart + " " + yStart);
    }

    public void move() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= SIZE * SIZE; i++) {
            moveGenerator();
            chessboard[x + xMove][y + yMove] = moveCount;
            moveCount++;
            x += xMove;
            y += yMove;
        }

        xEnd = x;
        yEnd = y;
    }

    public void moveGenerator() {
        int z = 0;

        while (z == 0) {
            randX = random.nextInt(5) - 2;

            if (randX % 2 == 0 && randX != 0) {
                randY = random.nextInt(3) - 1;
                if (randY != 0 && boundCheck() && newMoveCheck()) {
                    xMove = randX;
                    yMove = randY;
                    z = 1;
                }
            } else if (randX % 2 != 0) {
                randY = random.nextInt(5) - 2;

                if (randY != 0 && Math.abs(randY) > 1 && boundCheck() && newMoveCheck()) {
                    xMove = randX;
                    yMove = randY;
                    z = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean boundCheck() {
        return (randX + x) <= 7 && (randX + x) >= 0 && (randY + y) <= 7 && (randY + y) >= 0;
    }

    public boolean newMoveCheck() {
        return chessboard[randX + x][randY + y] == 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: I realized the problem is occurring in my move method I have to figure out a way to stop the loop once there are no more moves to make.